# How to get collection documents where field user_id using where

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got a problem while trying to get all document from a collection where the field user_id equal to user id.

This is my Firestore rule for the Contribution collection:

```
// ALLOW USER TO GET THEIR OWN CONTRIBUTION
    match /Contributions/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null; // && resource.data.user_id == request.auth.uid;
}
```

When I use this Flutter function, I get this output:

> I/flutter (22264): USER ID : ***myuserid***

```
Future<bool> getContributions(String userId) async {
    debugPrint("USER ID : " + userId);
    db
        .collection('Contributions')
        .where("user_id", isEqualTo: userId)
        .get()
        .then((data) => data.docs.forEach((doc) {
              debugPrint("BORDER ID : " + doc["border_id"]);
            }));
    return true;
  }
```

If I remove the where, I get this output:

> I/flutter (22264): USER ID : ***myuserid***
> I/flutter (22264): BORDER ID : ***documentId*** // it works !

```
Future<bool> getContributions(String userId) async {
    debugPrint("USER ID : " + userId);
    db
        .collection('Contributions')
        //.where("user_id", isEqualTo: userId)
        .get()
        .then((data) => data.docs.forEach((doc) {
              debugPrint("BORDER ID : " + doc["border_id"]);
            }));
    return true;
  }
```

I have attached my Firestore Contribution collection.

I already tried a lot of things, but I cannot figure out why my where isn't working.

I finnaly figured out why : i added by mistake a space while i copied the id. Take care about spaces in firestore.

Comment: check your Firestore database field ,is same as your code

Comment: i found by mistake i have added a space in firestore